# RecursionError in binary tree traversal

Tags: python, binary-tree

I know this has been asked before, but I really don't get what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to traverse a BST in pre-order fashion. The function below is member of a BST class, which contains `self.root`. Please help.

```
def pre_print(self, node=None):
  if not node:
    node = self.root
  print(node.data)
  self.pre_print(node.left)
  self.pre_print(node.right)
```

It keeps printing 2 or 3 values then I get this error

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: It's really hard to answer without seeing your class. But guessing, `pre_print` should be a method on nodes. Then you call it on each child: `self.left.pre_print()`. Test first that the `left` or `right` node is not `None`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need some initialization if no node is provided, just add a simple check

```
def pre_print(self, node=None):
  if not node:
    node = self.root
  print(node.data)
  if node.left:
    self.pre_print(node.left)
  if node.right:
    self.pre_print(node.right)
```

Comment: The function does nothing if I do that, That line is there to use the root node as a starting point if no other node is provided as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

When the recursion arrives at a point in which `self==(one of the leafs)`, I'm assuming its `node.left` and `node.right` are `==None`, at which point, the next recursion enters the `if` statement since its node arg is `==None` and then sets the ```node==(the self of the leaf node that called this function/method).root).

Which results in this function call being somewhat the similar to the one that was run before it. Resulting in a infinite recursion.

A simple check before entering your method can evade this problem.

```
def pre_print(self, node=None):
  if not node:
    node = self.root
  print(node.data)
  if node.left : self.pre_print(node.left)
  if node.right: self.pre_print(node.right)
```